# No URL for Apple ID Authorization - React Native

Tags: xcode, react-native

seeing a weird error when opening a web link in an embedded web view. This is a React Native application, and I am using react-native-webview for the embedded web view. The web link tries to load then either sits on a blank page or shows a "404 - there is no content available".

When I debugged in Xcode, the only error log that was shown was this one:

No URL for Apple ID Authorization

I have searched all over and could not find any reference to this error online. Has anyone run into this before? I am not using any SSO functionality, so not sure why I would be seeing an error like this. I reviewed the Apple documentation for the Apple SSO functionality and nothing jumped out to me.

Comment: when i've run into a similar problem, it's because the service base is unreachable.